# How can I access the parent key value in an multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [copier-clb009] => Array
        (
            [status] => Printing
            [ping] => PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.47 ms
            [model] => "Xerox WorkCentre 4265"
        )

    [copier-cor000] => Array
        (
            [status] => Printing
            [ping] => PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.53 ms
            [model] => "Xerox WorkCentre 4265"
        )

    [printer-001] => Array
        (
            [status] => Idle
            [ping] => PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.55 ms
            [model] => "Xerox Phaser 4600"
        )

    [printer-002-s1] => Array
        (
            [status] => Idle
            [ping] => PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.86 ms
            [model] => "Xerox WorkCentre 5955 v1 Multifunction System"
        )

)
```

For example, I have tried:

`echo $printers[0];`

and

```
echo array_values($printers)[0];
```

expecting for the results to be "copier-clb009", but neither of these works.  What am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your error is pretty clear here: *array_ **values** ($printers)[0]* ; You want to display a **key** and not a **value**. So you need  to get the keys and take the first one, e.g. *echo [array_ **keys**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) ($printers)[0];*

Comment: you need to print all key value or specific single key

Comment: FWIW, it's a lot saner to use something like [`var_export`](http://php.net/var-export) when pasting variable values in the form of code here, because `var_export` returns valid PHP code that anyone could copy/paste easily for testing. Also, for debugging variables purposes I recommend [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) over `print_r` any day. `var_dump` will offer you valuable information that `print_r` can't, like what type each variable/value is and if it's a string it also includes the string length in bytes, or array size if it's an array, which can be very helpful in many situations.

Comment: Ha - yep, that is pretty obvious.  Thanks Rizier123!  That is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear why you want to do that, but PHP already offers you a very convenient construct for iterating over traversable objects, like arrays, called [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach)

```
foreach($printers as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key => \n";
    foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        echo "$k: $v\n";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

The `foreach` construct gives you both access to the key and value of each element you're iterating with every iteration. So there's really no need to do any chicken pecking with `array_values` or `array_keys` here.

Comment: Perfect!  This is what I started with, but I was tripping up on the nested foreach, using ($value as...) was what I was missing - and also trying to access $value in the first foreach instead of the key.  I was trying to access them individual as a troubleshooting measure.  

It all seems so obvious now :)

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to go with foreach loop this will work for you.

```
foreach($printers as $key => $value){
    echo $key.'<br />';
}
```

this will print all your key
if you need to use specific key value you can set in variable according your requirement.